# Pass arguments to a thread while resuming it. (WINAPI)

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, winapi, arguments

I have a thread(Thread 1) which suspends another thread(Thread 2). After sometime, Thread1 resumes Thread2, but I want to pass a structure from Thread 1 to Thread 2 when Thread 1 resumes Thread 2.

How can I do it?

Comment: Both threads have access to the same memory - just use a struct and protect with some synchronisation.

Comment: Using synchronization-mechanisms like `Mutex`, `Event` and the like...

Comment: Can I use PostThreadMessage() to pass arguments from one thread to the other suspended thread and then resume the thread

Comment: Well, it won't process the message until it's resumed. But can't you simply give the pointer to the shared data to Thread2 at the time you create it?

Comment: You can *never* properly synchronize threads by using SuspendThread().  You have no idea what the suspended thread is doing, it might be allocating memory and has acquired the heap lock.  Thus deadlocking your entire program.  Scrap that approach.

Comment: @HansPassant : thank you for the help. Does that mean one should never use SuspendThread() ? in my case I have 50 threads all getting suspended and resumed. Should you prefer some other API over SuspendThread() ?

Comment: I agree with Hans - *never* use `SuspendThread` but instead use an event and `WaitForSingleObject` to manage the workload.

Comment: Indeed, the only way of suspending threads that won't byte you in the rear is `CREATE_SUSPENDED`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a message-driven thread. Design thread 2 so that it consists of a message loop using the GetMessage API. When it calls GetMessage it will suspend itself until a message arrives.

Then you can use PostThreadMessage to thread 2 and accomplish both goals. The message can carry a pointer to data to be processed, and receiving the message will unsuspend the thread. (I.e., the GetMessage call will return.)

After it processes the passed data it should then loop around to await the next message.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I think it is going to work + it is an easy implementation.